# where is “registry-1.docker.io” ？

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-registry

I do anything i can.
Not in daemon.json,maybe in some docker binary file.

```
   # cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
 
     {
        "registry-mirrors": [
        "https://d8b3zdiw.mirror.aliyuncs.com"
        ],
 
         "insecure-registries": [
       "https://ower.site.com"
```

This is docker info

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.7.1-docker)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.12.0)

Server:
 Containers: 25
  Running: 20
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 5
 Images: 13
 Server Version: 20.10.12
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc version: v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.701GiB
 Name: k8s-master
 ID: P6VN:S2FI:AU6D:LBCO:PPX7:KREJ:7OIQ:2K2J:XISF:MZGT:YSDB:XFIG
 Docker Root Dir: /data/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Disconnect the network,exec "kubectl create configmap nginx-config --from-file=nginx.conf",then,exec "kubectl describe pod nginx1-5c9f6bbd8c-4jmx2.
The messages display

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  34s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx1-5c9f6bbd8c-4jmx2 to k8s-master
  Warning  Failed     33s                kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": read tcp 10.15.29.150:51492->54.85.133.123:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

I want to know where is “registry-1.docker.io”.

Answer (score 3):

You are showing an issue with kubernetes, but making your configuration on docker. While these both run containers, they have separate configurations. For configuring the mirroring, it depends on how you run your containers in kubernetes. The most popular runtime being containerd's CRI, which has [documentation on configuring their registry settings](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/cri/registry.md):

`/etc/containerd/config.toml`:

```
version = 2

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
    endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io"]
```

Which has been replaced with:

`/etc/containerd/config.toml`:

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
   config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"
```

and

`/etc/containerd/certs.d/docker.io/hosts.toml`:

```
server = "https://docker.io"

[host."https://registry-1.docker.io"]
# ...
```

As for where `registry-1.docker.io` comes from, it's the DNS name for the Docker Hub registry, which is the default when you do not specify a registry in your image name.